# C# equivalent to this ColdFusion Decrypt function

Tags: c#, coldfusion, encryption

I have a function in ColdFusion that encrypts and decrypts passwords. I need someone to look at the function and point me to or write me a c# equivalent. It is needed for a project asap so I can throw you some cash through paypal if you can help.

CF function:

```
Decrypt("CLbtkjNkcofJ5D8s4Ri7nA==", "EajmplPP8DHg6Tqq8BVRMw==", "AES", "Base64")
```

This is the real function, with real data from a test side, that needs to be converted.

Any help would be awesome .. and profitable.

Thanks,
Donnie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your starting point would be [System.Security.Cryptography.Aes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx)

But these things can get quite hairy, for example you need to know which mode to use. Since your example is not showing an IV (initialization vector) you should use `CipherMode.ECB`.

Here is some test code, I will leave it to you to wrap this up in a nice re-usable function

```
  byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String("EajmplPP8DHg6Tqq8BVRMw==");
  byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String("CLbtkjNkcofJ5D8s4Ri7nA==");

  Aes aes = Aes.Create();
  aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(key, null), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
      cs.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    }
    byte[] decryptedData = ms.ToArray();
    string clearText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedData);
    Console.WriteLine(clearText);
  }
```

The answer => "AccessOne"

Comment: Chris you saved me. How can I get you some funds for the help?

Comment: FWIW, [ECB mode is discouraged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29).Both sides should be changed to use CBC mode instead.