# coldfusion decrypt to c#

Tags: c#, coldfusion, encryption

I copied and used the C# code in the sample from this page, [C# equivalent to this ColdFusion Decrypt function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396464/c-sharp-equivalent-to-this-coldfusion-decrypt-function) but it is not working for me. I'm not sure if the coldfusion decrypt sample on that page is the same as what I have. Anyway, my coldfusion code goes like this:

to encrypt:

```
<cfset strBase64Value = ToBase64(encrypt(strValue,"mykey")) />
```

to decrypt:

```
<cfset strDecrypted = decrypt(ToString(toBinary(strBase64Value)),"mykey") />
```

Where strValue is the string to begin with, strDecrypted is the returned decrypted string, strBase64Value is the encrypted string and "mykey" is the key password used to encrypt/decrypt strings.

My C# code follows:

```
    private string ConvertString(string string1, string string2)
    {
        byte[] key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string1);
        byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(string2);

        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(key, null), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
            }
            byte[] decryptedData = ms.ToArray();
            string clearText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedData);
            return clearText;
        }
    }
```

I get an error that says "The specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.
Parameter name: key"

Comment: what are your values for string1, string2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare password hashes between C# and ColdFusion (CFMX\_COMPAT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714155/compare-password-hashes-between-c-sharp-and-coldfusion-cfmx-compat)

Answer (score 3):

The linked example uses AES, which is a completely different algorithm.  Your code uses the old [cfmx_compat](http://cfdocs.org/decrypt) algorithm. There is no equivalent in the standard c# libraries. But here is [a c# port of cfmx_compat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4627069/104223) (ripped from the open source [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/) engine :).

That said, `cfmx_compat` is very insecure and only maintained for backward compatibility. I would strongly recommend switching to a more secure algorithm like AES, etcetera.